# Is the following a fundamental set?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y''' - 4y' = 0$$ Is $\{e^{2x}, e^{-2x}\}$  a fundamental set??

If I'm doing the wronskian correctly it is but the answer key shows that it is NOT a fundamental set.

Answer (score 3):

They *are* linearly independent, and so the $2 \times 2$ Wronskian determinant is nonzero for every $x$. However, you have a third order equation, so a basis for the solution set should have three elements (and the corresponding Wronskian should be $3 \times 3$, since it will incorporate second derivatives). In this case it is easy to fix your mistake: the other linearly independent solution is a constant.